# Rattling noise from the power steering reservoir

Tags: honda, power-steering, steering

Again, 2006 Honda Civic with R18A engine.

I'm hearing a rattling noise from the cabin and I have inspected all the suspension parts. Everything are nice and tight. Ball joints and rack ends also new.

Finally I was able to find the location that the rattle comes. When the steering wheel turning left and right quickly, I can hear this rattle from the power steering reservoir. Hose also vibrates, but nothing lose to rattle.

Is this something related to pressure relief valve? May be it is rattling or clogged?

Comment: Is the power steering fluid up to level? Does it have the correct power steering fluid in it? Honda has their own type of PS fluid. You can find non-OEM type for it, but it does require a different fluid than just plain generic PS fluid or automatic tranny fluid or it will cause problems.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yes fluid level and the fluid type is correct. However, I replaced steering rack shaft oil seals last day (2x main shaft seals and 1x pinion seal). I don't hear this rattle now.